# Van Kampen theorem fig-8

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

How to prove the Van Kampen theorem for the space of figure-eight
by showing that $\pi_1(X)$ can be expressed uniquely as finite product $<\alpha>^{m_1} <\beta>^{m_2} <\alpha>^{m_3}...$ where $m_1, m_2,..$ are integers and $m_j \ne 0, j>1$.

$\alpha$ is a loop on the first circle and $\beta$ on the second

Comment: Do you want "a proof" of the van Kampen theorem or *an application* of it?

Comment: I just want to prove that $π1(X)$ is the free group of two generators using the preceed argument

Answer (score 3):

The figure eight $\,V\,$ is just two circles $\, S^1\,$ joined by a common, unique point, say $\,x_0\,$, and clearly $\,\pi_1(\{x_0\})=\{1\}\,$ ,  and everything's path connected and happy and stuff, so the S-vK theorem tells us that

$$\pi_1(V)\cong\pi_1(S^1)\underset{\{1\}}*\pi_1(S^1)=\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z\cong F_2=\,\text{the free group on two generators}$$

Note the above amalgamated free product is just a "regular" free product since we're amalgaming over the trivial subgroup.

Comment: but i want the proof by showing that $\pi_1(X)$ can be expressed uniquely as finite product $<\alpha>^{m_1} <\beta>^{m_2} <\alpha>^{m_3}...$

Comment: If you already understood how and why is the theorem appliable then just "copy" the proof of the S-vK theorem from some book!